# ubuntu - Activation mail

Tags: php, email

I am trying to make a registration page on my localhost server, after the registration the person will receive a mail to confirm the registration. After hours of following tutorials all over the internet, I tried to write down a simple mail function to see if it worked.
The function:

```
<html>
<header>
<title> Test mail </title>
<?php
    mail("receiver@gmail.com","test mail","Hello!","sender@gmail.com");
    if (!mail("receiver@gmail.com","test mail","Hello!","sender@gmail.com")){
        echo "Mail not sent!";
    } else {
        echo "Mail sent!";
    }
?>
<body></body>
```

As output I will get (no errors, just this):

```
Mail not sent!
```

I have already configurate my php.ini and I already tried to use sendmailer en postfix. Does someone know what the problem may be? It would mean a lot for me.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the problem is not with PHP but your local mail setup. You should start by [manually verifying that your localhost can send mail](https://workaround.org/ispmail/lenny/test-mail-through-telnet). When you have successfully sent a test mail to an external address, you can continue debugging PHP, if necessary.

Also use Google and find pages [like this one](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1747373)

Comment: Thanks for the link! I followed all the steps, but it still doesn't work

Comment: Did you manage to send mail using telnet? If not, that's what you have to solve first, before using PHP.